# Could not download react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to install and run react-native app on an android emulator in my windows device but i keep getting this error

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.4/react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.4/react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar'.
> > This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.maven.apache.org)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 50s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Could not download react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.71.4)
> > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.4/react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/facebook/react/react-android/0.71.4/react-android-0.71.4-debug.aar'.
> > This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server (repo.maven.apache.org)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)
- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 50s

```
at makeError (C:\Users\PHANZ\Desktop\project\Kekeno\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\Users\PHANZ\Desktop\project\Kekeno\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\PHANZ\Desktop\project\Kekeno\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:82:7)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\PHANZ\Desktop\project\Kekeno\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:108:9)
```

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Having a similar issue. What I noticed, in the node_modules/react-native/android/ there is no aar and just a readme file saying this:

> Starting from React Native 0.71, we're not shipping the `/android`
> folder inside the React Native NPM package anymore due to sizing
> constraints on NPM. The Android artifacts are distributed via Maven
> Central. You can read more about it in this RFC:
> https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/pull/508
>
> If you're a library author and you're manipulating the React Native
> .aar files, to extract headers, extract `.so` files or do anything
> with it, you're probably doing something wrong. React Native
> 0.71 ships with all the necessary logic to let you consume it transparently by just using:
>
> ```
> implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android") 
> // or to keep
> backward compatibility with older versions of React Native:
> implementation("com.facebook.react:react-native:+")
> ```
>
> You should consider refactoring your library code not to
> unzip/manipulate the React Native .aar files.
>
> This README.md file is kept in this folder as some libraries are
> checking the existence of the /android folder and failing user
> builds if the folder is missing.

So I would try to add the implementation dependency and remove the task

Answer (score 0):

Based on your questions you can do 3 things here:

1. You can try clearing the Gradle cache by running the following command in the terminal:

```bash
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
```

2. If clearing the Gradle cache does not work, try updating Gradle to the latest version.

```bash
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 8.0.2
```

3. You can try increasing the stack size by adding the following line to your gradle.properties file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xss512m
```

This will increase the stack size to 512MB.

Let me know if it works now. I also would make sure your internet connection is stable.

Comment: I changed the gradle.property to    org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xss512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m but it still didnt work

Comment: Try updating Gradle